# Trouble loading bitmap texture atlas on screen

Tags: android, image, textures, andengine

I'm using AndEngine GLES2, and I tried to load an image on my phone but what I got was a black screen

Here are my code below:

```
public class BaseActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

public Font mFont;
public Camera mCamera;

private MainMenuScene mainMenuScene;
public Engine mEngine;
public Scene mScene;
public BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
public ITextureRegion mITextureRegion;



@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    instance = this;
    mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {

    mFont = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32);
    mFont.load();

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    mITextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "splash1.png");
    try {
        mBitmapTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 1));
    } catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    final float positionX = CAMERA_WIDTH * 0.5f;
    final float positionY = CAMERA_HEIGHT * 0.5f;
    Sprite mSprite = new Sprite(positionX, positionY, mITextureRegion, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mScene.attachChild(mSprite);
    return mCurrentScene;
}
```

The Logcat shows that I have a nullPointerException in my onCreateResources and onCreateScene, and I have no idea what has gone wrong. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One error was because you never created your Scene object, then tried to attach a sprite to it, the other was that the VertexbufferObjectManager is not that of the Engine class but of the SimpleBaseGameActivity class. onCreateScene() becomes:

```
    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {

        mScene = new Scene();
        final float positionX = CAMERA_WIDTH * 0.5f;
        final float positionY = CAMERA_HEIGHT * 0.5f;
        Sprite mSprite = new Sprite(positionX, positionY, mITextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mScene.attachChild(mSprite);
        return mScene;
    }
```

I also commented out some variables to make it build, though I suspect these are due to stripping down your code sample:

```
//        private MainMenuScene mainMenuScene;
//        instance = this;
```